# Script Enter key do the same thing as Search Button

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, inputformtextbox

I have a search box which filter Data from Sharepoint list developped with Javascript, here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">   function RedirectUrl(){var tb = document.getElementById("tbSearch").value; if(tb != null){window.location.href="?FilterName=Full_x0020_Name&FilterMultiValue=*"+tb+"*";}return false;}</script>

<input type="text" id="tbSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="search" onclick="return RedirectUrl();"/>
```

I want that when I press the Enter key in the Textbox, it do the same thing as when I click on Search Button, 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $('#tbSearch').keypress(function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
           //Your Code that you want to execute or simply call the function RedirectUrl()
        RedirectUrl();
        }
    });
```

You need [JQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) reference

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Hi Varun, Thanks for your Help. This code redirect me but dont put the value of my textbox in my URL, so what should I do ?

Comment: Use $(this).val() in place of tb in RedirectUrl function

Comment: I just Add return in front of redirecturl() and it works. Thanks Varun :)